# Fill in one EnumDropDownListFor based on the selection in another EnumDropDownListFor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm seeking for your help with ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have 3 enums:

```
    public enum Country
    {
        Canada = 1,
        USA = 2
    }

 public enum Provincies
    {
        Alberta,
        [Display(Name = "British Columbia")]
        BritishColumbia, 
        Manitoba,
        [Display(Name = "New Brunswick")]
        NewBrunswick,
        [Description("Newfoundlan And Labrador")]
        NewfoundlandAndLabrador,
        [Display(Name = "Nova Scotia")]
        NovaScotia, 
        Ontario,
        [Display(Name = "Prince Edward Island")]
        PrinceEdwardIsland, 
        Quebec,
        Saskatchewan
    }

public enum States
    {
        Alabama,
        Alaska,
        Arizona,
        Arkansas,
        California,
etc.
}
```

I'm using EnumDropDownListFor to populate those on a frontend, the only question is how can I make Province EnumDropDownListFor change based on the Country selection ? Do I need to use ajax (I think so but not sure how to populate EnumDropDownListFor with new values from another enum), or is there mo elegant way to do that that is there by default ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't think Enum fits with your requirement because you need to get both Value and Country name once you request via ajax.

Comment: Please try a static list implementation or a key-value object. Then post your initial code here.

Comment: @JerdineSabio Enumeration is already a key value object , isnt it ?

Comment: Hmm-- enum is a value type. It's like a static class with constant properties. You won't be able to filter it, you'll also have a hard time getting the display attribute if you call via ajax.

Comment: How about-- create 2 enum dropdowns one for States and Provinces then just hide and show them depending on the value of the country dropdown?

Comment: Not sure how to filter through Enum , can you make an example of it  please ? @JerdineSabio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing you could do is use Jquery to show the correct dropdown based on the selected country enumeration. Here is an exaple in which I use a model with your enumerations

```
public class Info
{
    public Enumeration.Country Countries { get; set; }
    public Enumeration.States States { get; set; }
    public Enumeration.Provincies Provincies { get; set; }
}
```

In your view use

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(u => u.Countries)
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(u => u.Countries, "Select Country", new { id = "CountriesDroDownLst" })
<hr />
<div class="provinciesContainer hidden">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(u => u.Provincies)
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(u => u.Provincies)
    <hr />
</div>
<div class="statesContainer hidden">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(u => u.States)
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(u => u.States)
    <hr />
</div>
```

and finally a simple jquery script which will hide or show the enumeration dropdown based on the selected value. (CANADA:1, USA:2)

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $("#CountriesDroDownLst").change(function (e) {
            $(".statesContainer, .provinciesContainer").addClass("hidden");
            var container = ($(this).val() === "1") ? ".provinciesContainer" : ".statesContainer";
            $(container).toggleClass("hidden");
        });
    </script>
}
```

So everytime the user selects USA then the Canada dropdown will be hidden and the other way around. If you want to hide both dropdowns if nothing is selected then change your script like this

```
$("#CountriesDroDownLst").change(function (e) {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $(".statesContainer, .provinciesContainer").addClass("hidden");
    if (selectedValue === "0")
        return;
    $(".statesContainer, .provinciesContainer").addClass("hidden");
    var container = (selectedValue === "1") ? ".provinciesContainer" : ".statesContainer";
    $(container).toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: Yeah I though about it but is it kinda a workaround for that. I will accept this answer because there are no other options comming my way and thanks for your time writing down the code ! I appreciate it

Comment: This is the simplest way. You can also do this by using an ajax call and dynamically populate a single dropdown. If you'd like I can provide that way too.

Comment: Thanks a bunch ! I think I know how you would do that. Simply create a VModel with property type Enum and will change it depending on the user country selection